# Why does 縱 mean both "loose; vertical; although; even if"

Tags: etymology

|  | 詞類 | 英文意義 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **v.** | loose; allow; relax; let go; let fly; be indulgent; release; set free |
| 2 | **adj.** | vertical; perpendicular; longitudinal; lengthwise |
| 3 | **conj.** | ***although*** |
| 4 | **idiom** | ***even if; granted that*** |

http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%B8%B1 wrote that "可能由於絲織品是由直線和橫線編織而成，故「縱」後來表示「直」，與「橫」相對。" Here's my translation in English — perhaps because silk fabrics are woven from straight and horizontal threads, 「縱」means straight, as opposed to "horizontal".

3. But  the website did not elaborate   3 and 4? How is "***although***" related to "本義是一種絲織品。"?
4. How is "***even if; granted that***" related to "本義是一種絲織品。"?

Comment: Do you need this-->  http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/cgi-bin/agrep-lindict?query=%C1a&category=wholerecord

Comment: @envs_h_gang_5 what do you mean? are you suggesting that link to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

『說文解字』- "**(縱)緩也。一曰捨也**。各本作舍也，由俗以舍捨通用也。今正。**捨者，釋也**。从糸從聲。足用切。九部。**後人以爲從衡(橫)字者，非也。**"

As indicated above, 縱 means "although", since it implies the relation of one "yield to" another, which is similar to the original meaning - "relax/release and soften"; as well as the idioms derived from it "縱使(even if),縱令(even though)".

『說文解字』disputes the origin of the word has something to do with 衡(transverse, horizontal, also 橫), for which, 豎 (vertical) is clearly the counterpart of it. This dispute puts the association of the origin of 縱 with the orientation of the threads in the (silk) fabrics in doubt, if not completely brushed aside. From this, your questions could well be based on a potentially "false" claim that bears no answer.

Answer (score 0):

> 「縱」後來表示「直」，與「橫」相對

縱 -- a vertical line **extends forward**

橫 - a horizontal line extends sideways

縱 (extends forward) --> let go --> allow --> indulge

> 縱: although; even if; granted that

> (**allow** one factor doesn't make other factors in a situation reasonable/ inevitable)

Example:

縱死不懼 - not afraid **even if/ although** facing death

you allow (accept) the fact that you are facing death, but it still doesn't make fear inevitable

Comment: thanks. what do you mean by "(**allow** one factor doesn't make other factors in a situation reasonable/ inevitable)" ? I do not understand how you leaped from "allow" to "even if" and "although". Pls elaborate?

Comment: For example,   allow the fact that an item is expensive, but it isn't a strong enough reason for you to not buy it. Put it into context, we  got "although it is expensive, I am still buying it"